# Horizontal scrolling in Slingshot application launcher is very sensitive

Tags: release-loki, slingshot

I have three pages of applications in my launcher, but I find it difficult to access the second page of applications because of how sensitive the horizontal scrolling is in the launcher. When using other applications (i.e. my browser), I don't find the scroll speed to be an issue, however. Is there a way to configure the scroll speed for slingshot?